# USB device not detected by Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, usb, drivers

I have a recording device, a [yamaha Pocketrak w24](http://www.yamahaproaudio.com/global/en/products/recorders_players/pocketrakw24/) with built-in storage. On my old laptop (Windows 7 64 bit) I had no problem hooking it up to the computer and downloading all files. On my new windows 8.1 it fails to show up in the explorer. The device says it's connected to the computer, but it's nowhere to be found by my OS.

I tried finding a driver for it, but apart from some fishy sites that ask me to install a "driver scanner and updater" of dubious nature, I find nothing. Tried scanning for new devices, but still nothing shows up. Tried all USB ports, restarting my laptop, nothing works.

If I look in the device manager, it's not visible either (neither under disk drives nor under USB controllers).

Is there a way to tell Windows 8 where the device is and how it's working?

---

UPDATE : 
I reinstalled all USB drivers, but no succes.
I uninstalled all USB mass storage device drivers (also the hidden ones), to no avail.
I use [USBview](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Utilities.htm) to check what's going on, and I get a warning that is not showing up in my device manager :

DeviceGeneralFailure at Loc1f. I get some other warnings saying 'PIP not found'.

Apparently my machine is set up with some internal USB hubs and the bluetooth device attached to it somewhere. I attached a screenshot of USBView. If anybody can tell me what's going wrong here, please enlighten me.

[image]

PS: The USB input device is my mouse. For the rest nothing is attached to any visible USB port.

Comment: Did you have any software CD that came with it?

Comment: @SaUce That's about the first thing I checked. Alas, nothing. I didn't have any trouble on my previous machine either.

Comment: When you look at device manager do you find any unknown USB devices? You can try to uninstall all drivers that windows loaded and try again. I know that depending to which port I plug in my USB storage it takes it or not.

Comment: Tried everything, including uninstalling all redundant drivers for unconnected USB devices. Still nothing